# Is there a way to enable multithreaded rendering with ARCore or ARInterface on Unity for a device?

Tags: android, multithreading, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am working on an AR project, on iOS(Tested on iPad Pro, iPhone 6s, iPhone X) with ARKit I have much, much better performance than on Android (Samsung S8). I believe it is because I have multithreaded rendering enabled on the iOS versions, but on Android, I can't enable it. When I try to build it with multithreaded rendering I get the "tango does not support multi-threaded rendering when color camera is used" error. For reference I have 30 fps in one scene on iOS, on Android I have 3.

So my question is, is there a workaround for this? The only thread I could find that is remotely relevant was this :"[Camera texture in Unity with multithreaded rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324870/camera-texture-in-unity-with-multithreaded-rendering)" but it is about tango and I can't find the same options for the ARCore. I also tried the ARInterface and I had the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the answer is no right now. I kind of doubt it, but this might help you: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/141

See the second comment.

In `ARCoreSessionConfig.cs` change line 37 to false:
`public bool MatchCameraFramerate = flase;`